# Reference to a comment by Arthur C. Clarke

Tags: reference-request, astronomy

In one of his non-fiction works, probably "Mysterious World" or "World of Strange Powers", Arthur C. Clarke tells an anecdote about an astronomers' expedition to Africa (if I remember correctly) to observe a solar eclipse. The local population mocks the "arrogant" foreigners who believe to know in advance what the Sun will do. After the eclipse, the astronomers ask the locals whether they have changed their mind. Not at all, they reply, but concede that it was an interesting coincidence.

Does anyone have the exact quote and the reference?

My apologies if this is not the right community to ask.

Comment: Is probably from here, see episode 1: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_C._Clarke%27s_Mysterious_World

Comment: It does not appear in the book that accompanies it, but here is a YouTube link to the first episode: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8mEJ7iPhQ-0&ab_channel=LowFlyingAircraft

Comment: @Mauricio Thanks, but I couldn't find it in the episode. As far as I remember, I read it somewhere, not heard or saw.

Comment: I reckon that it is not exactly as shown, but is it possible that you are mixing two different accounts?